# Why do functions in Vimscript require a "call" statement?

Tags: vimscript

In Vimscript, if you use a function as an R-value (right hand side value) of an assignment statement, then the function simply evaluates. For example:

```
let count_pattern += str2nr( strpart( execute( command ), 1 ) )
```

However, if a function is used not as an R-value of an assignment statement, then a "call" keyword must be used:

```
call substitute( current_line, '\d\+', '\=add( listValues, submatch(0) )', 'g')
```

What is the necessity for the use of the "call" keyword? In most languages one can simply use a function by itself as a statement, but apparently in Vimscript you cannot.

Comment: I have been scripting vim for over a decade and have nearly 4k lines in my vimrc. I use vim very heavily. Only today did I actually learn the pattern behind when I'm supposed to use `call`. Thank you so much for clarifying it in your question.

Comment: @StevenLu Uh, ok. Are you going to upvote the question then?

Comment: Ask and you shall receive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMO, we have to consider that `vi` and `ed` had ex-commands, and that `vim` introduces functions.

When `vim` interprets a line, it needs a way to distinguish `:substitute` from `substitute()`, or `:MyUserThing` (which is a command) from `MyUserThing()` (which is a function).

That's why `:call` is required. As `:let`, this is an ex-command. The difference between these two is that the result will be ignored as we don't need it, but this is anecdotal. What's important is to be able to distinguish ex-commands from function calls.

Comment: Ahh. So, in the question of OP, the "functions" in the R-value is not a function call in the first place, rather they're ex commands? Or is it that these are actually functions but when used in R-value, they act as ex commands?

Comment: @klaus The OP was wondering why he couldn't write `:substitute( current_line, '\d\+', '\=add( listValues, submatch(0) )', 'g')` without the `:call`. The reason is likely that Vim has no way to know that the end-user wants to call a function and not a command with `(whatever)` as command parameter. `:call` is required to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: But couldn't that be made unambiguous by checking out that substitute has `()` after it? And my query was in `let count_pattern += str2nr( strpart( execute( command ), 1 ) )`, is `execute(command)` a function call or an ex command?

Comment: @klaus No because `(whatever)` could be a perfect parameter for a command.

Comment: @klaus, the ex-command is `:let` here. What is after the equal sign is an expression.

Answer (score 6):

**Hypothesis**:
When you're using a function as an R-value, or right hand side value, of an assignment statement, you're trying to assign the output of the R-value to the L-value variable.

**Why `call` is needed when calling a function**:
From the documentation (see `:h call`) it is evident that `call` will discard the return value of a function.

```
                                        *:cal* *:call* *E107* *E117*
:[range]cal[l] {name}([arguments])
        Call a function.  The name of the function and its arguments
        are as specified with |:function|.  Up to 20 arguments can be
        used.  The returned value is discarded.
```

So, since when you're using functions as R-value you don't want to discard the output of the function, rather want to assign it to the L-value, you don't use call.

Moreover, you don't always need `call` to call a function. You can pass the function to another function for example,

```
:function GetMeow()
:  return "Meow String!"
:endfunction

:GetMeow()       " ERROR!

:call GetMeow()  " no output

:echom GetMeow() " shows "Meow String!"
```

**Edit**

Many languages have the notion of "statements" and "expressions" and programs are generally sequences of statements. In C, `GetMeow()` may be an expression but `GetMeow();` (with a semicolon) is a statement. In vim, `GetMeow()` is an expression but `call GetMeow()` is a statement, which are referred to as `ex commands`. It's really not as strange as the question implies.

Comment: `GetMeow()` example is from [Learn Vimscript The Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/23.html) by the way.

Comment: vimscript is a sequence of (ex) commands, not expressions, and only some of these commands interpret expressions (call, echom, let, etc).  I see new users frequently confused by why say, `:set option=g:value` or `:buffer g:buf` won't work.  some commands like execute and echo are even capable of interpreting multiple expressions: e.g., `echo 1 + 2 3 + 4` is well formed

Comment: I don't understand. Did I leave something out of my answer? Or is there a mistake? You can edit the answer if you want.

Comment: I don't really see how the quoted documentation for `:call` explains why `:GetMeow()` is an error. From my understanding, it's the latter that the question is really about. @Mass's comment seems to touch on the reasoning, but could do with some fleshing out before becoming a full answer (or possibly integrated into this one).

Comment: @klaus, Although your answer is factual, I felt like it did not address a critical distinction.  Many languages have the notion of "statements" and "expressions" and programs are generally sequences of statements.  In C, `GetMeow()` may be an expression but `GetMeow();` (with a semicolon) is a statement.  In vim, `GetMeow()` is an expression but `call GetMeow()` is a statement, which are referred to as ex commands.  It's really not as strange as the question implies.

Comment: @Mass, I had no idea, because I have zero knowledge of vimscript as a language. Anyway, I added your comment to my answer. The thing is I didn't even think about that line of thought because vimscript always felt kinda like python, and python AFAIK has little distinction between statements and expressions. And you should edit the answer, it will become more clear then to understand. Thanks.

Comment: @8bittree, I thought in vimscripts, functions needed to be called with `call` keyword because otherwise the return value would not be used. Kind of like how C compilers give warning when a function returns something but you don't store it in a variable. Anyway, I edited my answer. Please, check if everything is alright.

Comment: how to keep the return value?