# How to I insert a return value from a function call into an existing buffer?

Tags: functions

This following vim script calls a function that returns an array called `lines`:

`call vimwiki#diary#generate_diary_section()`

There seems to be a bug and nothing is done with the `lines` array—the content never gets added to the buffer. I have a two part question:

1. How do I capture the array returned from the function? I tried `let lines = call ...` but that didn't work.
2. How to I dump the lines in the array into the existing file?

Comment: The only time you use `call` is when you don't care about the function's return value. Since you're using the return value here you must leave it off (`let foo = somefunc(...)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to insert the return value of a function into a buffer, but the simplest (in my opinion) is to use the expression register:

In normal mode you can trigger the expression register with `"=`, and then you type an expression and hit enter (`<CR>`). Thiss can just be a function call, if you wish; then, press `p` or `P` to put, as usual. So, `"=vimwiki#diary#generate_diary_section()<CR>p`.

Alternatively, you can use the `:put[!]` command:

```
put =vimwiki#diary#generate_diary_section()
```

This works linewise.

As for why `:call vimwiki#diary#generate_diary_section()` doesn't do anything, it's because `:call` explicitly discards return values. You can `:echo` to see the value, or use `:let` to bind it to a variable. But if you just want to insert it directly, `:put` or `p` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `call`.
[This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19186/30239) did explain the `call` keyword in `vim`.