# Calling function without using call

Tags: functions

This is just my own curiosity speaking here, but would it be possible (if it's even possible by default in normal `vim`, without any additional plugins etc) to call a function inside a vimscript function *without* having to use `call`?

I'm thinking of emulating or doing things like when special function/keywords like `echo` and other builtin are called:

```
function! Test()
echo something
endfunction
```

above we can see we do not need to use `call` to run `echo`. Would it be possible to do the same on a function we make ourselves? eg: replace `echo` above with `Myfunction` but without having to use `call`.

To make myself more clear: I already know this is possible for function defined as commandline or [user defined commands](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands), where one can just do `:Myfunction` in Ex mode, but that isn't what I want to do, although it is similar in that it does not need the use of `call`.

P.S: While I mentioned earlier wanting to know if it's possible in *normal* vim (eg: without plugins etc) I wouldn't mind knowing if it's still possible using plugins either, but the main point here is still knowing if it's possible without them.

Comment: Functions and Ex commands are different namespaces in Vim. `echo` works without `call` because it's an Ex command and not a function. You can define functions, that you then can use with `:call` or `:eval` or within Vimscript expressions (for example, as arguments to `:echo` or to `:let`). You can define new Ex commands as user-defined commands (though with the restriction they need to start with uppercase.) So you can either use `:call` on functions, or create a user-defined command, either would accomplish what you're asking here...

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for the added clarification -- noticed statox's answer works, so that was just me misunderstanding. :D

Comment: It relates to the need to distinguish ex-commands from function calls. There are a few overlaps like `:substitute` and `substitute()`, `insert`... https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19142/why-do-functions-in-vimscript-require-a-call-statement

Comment: didn't find this when I searched. Nice :D It does explain things further as to why it is the way it is. @LucHermitte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need that in this context but you could use a user defined command ([`:h user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands)):

```
function MyFunction(argument)
    echo a:argument
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 Myfunc call MyFunction(<args>)
```

With this you can use `:Myfunc "hello"` from the command line and you will get the result of `echo "hello"`, this is the most common use of user defined commands.

But it also means that you can use that in any vimscript file.

There is a lot to read about how to use these [`:h :command-completion`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-completion),[`:h :command-nargs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-nargs), [`:h :command-range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-range)...

Comment: I know how to make user defined command, and I also know how to do it like you did here so that I don't need to use `call` on the commandline...but my question was to do this but for *function* outside of commandline :)

Comment: basically, following your answer, instead of doing `:Myfunc "hello"` I want to know how to do `Myfunc "hello"` inside a vimscript function *outside* of commandline (eg: without having to do `call Myfunc "hello"` when using it inside a function)

Comment: I understand and that's why 1) I said I don't see why you would need to do that: I don't see any advantage to have two different ways to call the same function in a piece of code. In the command line I understand that shortness is an advantage but not in code. 2) I suggested that you use commands because that is the probably the only solution you have to call a function without the keyword `call`

Comment: I see. that's understandable :) I appreciate the effort to convey that which is why I upvoted it, but if there isn't any way to do this, I guess that still good to know.

Comment: wait...I just tried what you said and it looked like this works as I wanted it to if I put `Myfunc "hello"` inside a function called `Test` and then try it for testing using `call`. it work so I guess I misunderstood :)

Comment: I still think it's a big anti-pattern and you should not do that until you have a very good reason because all it does is adding an unnecessary level of indirection in your code. But it's great that it answers your question :)

Comment: don't worry, even if i do use this, you won't see me doing this on any public codebase (and even then, I would probably document it). This is mostly for my own personal use cases but I appreciate the advice nonetheless :D

Answer (score 2):

Oh, well. It is absolutely **not** about "call". It is about command-line mode (or sourcing a script which is almost the same thing).

In command-line mode everything **must** start with a command. It could be `call foo()` or `eval foo()` or `let xyz = foo()` or thousand of other constructs. But they all start with a command that accepts an expression. Not with function name (i.e. expression itself). So easy.

Comment: please, reread my edited post. I'm well aware it's possible on commandline mode or Ex mode -- my question was about doing this inside a function in vimscript *outside* commandline mode (eg: inside a .vimrc for example)

Comment: @NordineLotfi Re-read my answer. It is almost the same thing.

Comment: @NordineLotfi People seem always to miss this. VimScript is much like shell scripting: there's only marginal difference between "interactive" and "script" modes.

Comment: I re-read it many times, but to me it isn't almost the same thing :/ you're essentially saying "they all need to start with a command that accept an expression", but I already know that (and also doesn't apply when one is doing [user defined commands](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands) which is also not what I want to do)

Comment: And yes, I'm well aware that the syntax/the way vimscript work is similar to shell scripting. But! in shell scripting one can always call a function inside a script *without* having to have something before it to call said function. It's basically what I want to do here, but again, without having to use `call`. :)

Comment: @NordineLotfi It does apply to user-commands as well. To define a command you must start with command named `:command`. And its body must start with yet another command (e.g. `:call`). And function definition also starts with a command named `:function`. And so on, and so on.

Comment: Vimscript is a collection of Ex commands. As a Vim function is not an Ex command, you need to use the ":call" Ex command to invoke the function. Note that in a Vim9script, this has been addressed and you can invoke a function without using ":call".